# Extjs 4 store - query entire store not just cached records

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I need to be able to retrieve records from a remote/proxy store beyond the cached records that reside in memory. Is there a way to do this with Ext? The documentation hasn't been much help.

So I have a normal store that works with paging or buffered scrolling just fine

```
store = Ext.create('Ext.data.DirectStore', {
    autoLoad: true,
    pageSize: 30,
    remoteFilter: true,
    remoteSort: true,
    proxy: Ext.create('Ext.data.proxy.Direct', {...});
}
```

My store currently contains 97 items, but only 30 are cached

```
console.log('store',store.getTotalCount()); // outputs 97
console.log('RANGE', store.getRange().length); // outputs 30
var count = 0;
store.queryBy(function (record) {
    console.log(++count); // outputs 0 -> 30
    return true;
});
```

So no matter what logic I put in the `queryBy` function, only 30 cached records are tested. I've tried using `filterBy` and the `remoteFilter` setting in the store but this gives the same results. So are there any other techniques that I could try?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does `store.data.length` return?

Comment: It returns the same as getRange().length, 30

Comment: That's just how paging works, only the data that is returned from the server is loaded into the store.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli good point, I overlooked that.  The `totalCount` (which is returned by `getTotalCount()`) is set based on the `totalProperty` value in the response from the server.

Comment: Backing up for a moment, what's the problem you're trying to solve? It seems like the Store is really fighting you on this, and maybe there's some other way.

Comment: You probably don't have 97 records in the store. Using `store.getTotalCount()` only uses the total property on the store, which can be manipulated inside the stores reader.

If you actually had 97 records in the store, you could use `store.getRange()`, but my guess is that you don't. Since you are using paging, I am assuming you load 30 records and then load 30 more records (from a web service) when the user goes to the next page. 

When the user clicks the next page, the store is emptied and reloaded with the new records, therefore, the first 30 records no longer exist in the store.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've used ExtJS, but I believe that you can use `store.getRange()` to get the behavior that you want (with no arguments, it should return the full contents of the store). According to the documentation, filtering is taken into account for this, so you should be able to apply whatever filters you need to get the desired set of records.

Comment: getRange() only seems to return the current page. In the question I put a console.log of the size of getRange and it returned smaller than the totalcount.